# need help with uploading box for xml using php form

Tags: php, xml

i have script that allow me to upload photo but I need to upload 2 photos ( photo+ thumbnail) at single post and to add to lines to xml file (filename and thumbnail).

My index.php

```
//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$filename;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}}


 ?>

 <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" and use an input type "file" -->
 <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
 <table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
 </table>   
 </form>
```

my galley.xml

```
<photos>
    <photo>
        <thumbnail>s_flashmo_175_01.jpg</thumbnail>
        <filename>flashmo_175_01.jpg</filename>
    </photo>

</photos>
```

thanks 2 all .

Comment: What is the question...?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) this will let you resize and copy your larger image into a thumbnail size image